# Recursively read images from subdirectories

Tags: matlab, subdirectory

I am stuck on something that is supposed to be so simple.

I have a folder, say `main_folder` with four sub folders, say `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3` and `sub4` each containing over 100 images. Now am trying to read and store them in an array. I have looked all over the internet and some MATLAB docs:
[here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92761-how-can-i-recursively-process-files-in-subdirectories-using-matlab), [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32038-can-you-use-dir-to-list-files-in-subfolders) and even the [official doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).

My code is like this:

```
folder = 'main_folder/**'; %path containing all the training images
dirImage = dir('main_folder/**/*.jpg');%rdir(fullfile(folder,'*.jpg')); %reading the contents of directory

numData = size(dirImage,1);    %no. of samples

arrayImage = zeros(numData, 133183); % zeros matrix for storing the extracted features from images

for i=1:numData
        ifile = dirImage(i).name;
%         ifolder = dirImage(i).folder;
        I=imread([folder, '/', ifile]);  %%%% read the image  %%%%%
        I=imresize(I,[128 128]);
        ...
```

If I try the code in the above snippet, the images are not read. 
But if I replace the first two lines with something like:

```
folder = 'main_folder/'; %path containing all the training images
dirImage = dir('main_folder/sub1/*.jpg'); %rdir(fullfile(folder,'*.jpg'));
```

then all images in `sub1` are read. How can I fix this? Any help will be highly appreciated. I want to read all the images in the four sub folders at once.
I am using MATLAB R2015a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to use `genpath` to get all sub-folders, and then loop through each of them, like:

```
dirs = genpath('main_folder/'); % all folders recursively
dirs = regexp(dirs, pathsep, 'split'); % split into cellstr
for i = 1:numel(dirs)
    dirImage = dir([dirs{i} '/*.jpg']); % jpg in one sub-folder
    for j = 1:numel(dirImage)
        img = imread([dirs{i} '/' dirImage(j).name]);
        % process img using your code
    end 
end
```

Comment: thanks. this solves the issue. Why doesn't the code on the MATLAB document website work? is it a version difference based problem? or what?